# Problem with finding some three points for non-monotonic function

Tags: analysis

Let $f:(a,b|) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function which is not monotonic. I wish to prove that there are numbers $x<y<z$ from $(a,b)$ such that

$ f(x)>f(y)<f(z)$

or

$f(x)<f(y)>f(z)$.

By monotonic function $f$ I mean that $f$ is either nonincreasing  ($x<y \Rightarrow f(x) \geq f(y)$) or nondecreasing ($x<y \Rightarrow f(x) \leq f(y)$).

Comment: What is the definition of monotonic ?

Comment: Is your function continuous?

Comment: If it is needed, we can assume continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slightly tedious but very straightforward way to prove the desired result. Since $f$ is not monotone, in particular it’s not non-increasing, so there are $u,v\in(a,b)$ such that $u<v$ and $f(u)<f(v)$. Similarly, $f$ is not non-decreasing, so there are $s,t\in(a,b)$ such that $s<t$ and $f(s)>f(t)$. Now consider the various possible relationships amongst $s,t,u$, and $v$; I’ll do three of the cases to get you started.

- If $s<t\le u<v$, either $f(t)<f(v)$, in which case $f(s)>f(t)<f(v)$, or $f(t)\ge f(v)$, in which case $f(s)>f(u)<f(v)$.
- If $s\le u<t\le v$, either $f(u)<f(t)$, in which case $f(s)>f(u)<f(t)$, or $f(u)\ge f(t)$, in which case $f(s)>f(t)<f(v)$.
- If $s\le u<v<t$, either $f(s)<f(v)$, in which case $f(s)<f(v)>f(t)$, or $f(s)\le f(v)$, in which case $f(u)<f(v)>f(t)$.

---

An alternative is to suppose that $f$ does not have the desired property and show that $f$ must be monotone on each interval $[u,v]$ such that $a<u<v<b$. Then let $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a strictly decreasing sequence converging to $a$ and $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ a strictly increasing sequence converging to $b$ such that $a<a_0<b_0<b$. Use the fact that $f$ is monotone on each of the intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ to show that $f$ must be monotone.

Answer (score 1):

Because of f cannot be 1-1 there are distinct u, v such that f(u) = f(v) with the derivatives f ’(u) or f ’(v) non null and f non constant on the  [u,v]; this interval contains the three required points no matter of the continuity of f (but of course with [u, v] contained in the domain of f). You can add details.

Answer (score 0):

consider compact sets $C_n=[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$ after some stage (say $N$) such that $C_n$ is contained in $(a,b)$ and if $f$ is continuous then $f$ achieves both max an min on $X_n$. Now if assume contrapositive then $f$ achieves max and min on endpoints of $X_n$ for all $n>N$. Now wolg we can assume $f$ achieves max at $a+\frac{1}{n}$ and min at $b-\frac{1}{n}$ on $X_n$ for all $n>N$ and now $n \to \infty \implies$ $f$ is decreasing

Comment: Is a continuity assumption in a question (in this proof yes)  essential?